# Android FusedLocationApi Location Service Not Working Properly using Runtime Permission API 23

Tags: android, android-service, fusedlocationproviderapi, location-services, google-location-services

Can anybody help me to solve problem:

`onConnected()` method  why my

```
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
```

code not executing; and retrun from `checkSelfPermission()`

what can i do to work `FusedLocationApi` properly in this code

my code is below

```
public class JMSCLocationService extends Service implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener {
    private final String TAG = "MyAwesomeApp";
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    // Check Permissions Now
    private static final int REQUEST_LOCATION = 2;
    //private final double radiusInMeters = 1609.34;
    private final double radiusInMeters = 16.34;
    LatLng firstLatLong;
    Location fLoc;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection has STARTED");
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();

        firstLatLong = new LatLng(0, 0);
        Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection has STARTED");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // disconnect the client.
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected())
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // Connect the client.
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null && !mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient.connect();");
        }


        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient.isConnected();");
        }
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000); // Update location every second

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            //return;
        }
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection has been suspend");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection has failed");

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location mCurrentLocation) {
        Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient Location received: " + mCurrentLocation.toString());
        //test outside
        double mLatitude = mCurrentLocation.getLatitude();
        double mLongitude = mCurrentLocation.getLongitude();
        if(firstLatLong.latitude == 0.0 && firstLatLong.longitude == 0.0){
            firstLatLong = new LatLng(mLatitude,mLongitude);
            fLoc=new Location(mCurrentLocation);
        }
        float[] results = new float[1];
        Location.distanceBetween(firstLatLong.latitude, firstLatLong.longitude,
                mLatitude, mLongitude, results);

        float distanceInMeters = fLoc.distanceTo(mCurrentLocation);
        try{
            if( distanceInMeters > radiusInMeters ){
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Outside, distance from center", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Inside, distance from center", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }catch (Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to request the permissions. You are just checking whether your app has the permission.

You are ignoring the result of `checkSelfPermission()` in your code.

Read the comments, they are self explanatory.

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            //return;
        } else {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
}
```

Read about requesting runtime permissions from :

1. https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html#perm-request
2. http://www.truiton.com/2016/04/obtaining-runtime-permissions-android-marshmallow-6-0/

### Edit 1

I think by ***...but at compile time in service it's gives error for must use selfcheck permission*** you mean the Lint warnings.

You can suppress them by adding `@SuppressWarnings("MissingPermission")` on top of the method in which you are calling `requestLocationUpdates()`.

But make sure you have are calling `requestLocationUpdates()` iff you have the permission for it *(Mind the `if..else` block)*.

Comment: i have used Service not Activity to get Location how i can do this in Service

Comment: You must request for the permission from your `Activity` before starting the `Service`. Start the service only when user grants permission.

Comment: yes but i have taken permission form actvity, but at compile time in service it's gives error for must use selfcheck permission

Comment: Have you added `LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(...)` inside `else`block?

Answer (score 0):

USE:

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 
            REQUEST_ID);
    }else{
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
            mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
}
```

AND:

```
 @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_ID: {
                for( int i = 0; i < permissions.length; i++ ) {
                    if( grantResults[i] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        Log.d("Permissions", "Permission Granted: " + permissions[i]);
                    } else if( grantResults[i] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED ) {
                        Log.d( "Permissions", "Permission Denied: " + permissions[i] );
                    }
                }
            }
                break;
            default:
                super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
```

Comment: i have used extend Service, and this is not allow me to @Override this method

Comment: then when you start service call this method. if you have permission then start service

Comment: I have taken permission on activity, but when i run code method return from selfcheck()

Comment: yse if i remove selfcheck() from service and only take permission from  activity it's give error to must use self check or SecutiryException

Comment: then it give SecurtyException error in printstackstrace